# RadzenPanel expand icon on left

Tags: icons, panel, expand, radzen

I'm looking for a way to move the expand/collapse icon in a RadzenPanel from the (default) right to the left. Thank you in advance.

[image: Radzen Panel]

Answer (score 0):

Disregard. The solution is:

```
/* Move Expand/Collapse icon to the left */
.rz-panel-titlebar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.rz-panel-titlebar-icon {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```